# C# - Constructor with generic parameters transmitting these parameters to base constructor

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

There are so many problems approaching mine on this site, while being different, that I cannot find the answer.
I struggle with the restrictions on polymorphism brought about by generic classes.

1. CW1Message:

   ```
    public abstract class CW1Message {
        private CW1Connection _ConnectionConfig;

        protected CW1Message(CW1Connection conn) {
            ConnectionConfig = conn;
        }

        protected internal CW1Connection ConnectionConfig { get => _ConnectionConfig; set => _ConnectionConfig = value; }
    }
   ```
2. CW1Request and CW1Response:

   ```
    public abstract class CW1Request<ResponseType> : CW1Message where ResponseType : CW1Response {
        protected CW1Request(CW1Connection conn) : base(conn) {

        }

        protected abstract string RootElement { get; }
        protected abstract string XMLNameSpace { get; }
        protected virtual string XMLVersion { get => null; }
        protected virtual string SubRootElement { get => null; }

        protected XElement getRoot(XDocument requestDoc) {
            if (requestDoc.Root.Name != RootElement) {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Le document XML fournit ne contient pas les éléments attendus.");
            }
            if (SubRootElement == null) {
                return requestDoc.Root;
            } else {
                if (requestDoc.Root.Element(SubRootElement).Name != SubRootElement) {
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Le document XML fournit ne contient pas les éléments attendus.");
                }
                return requestDoc.Root.Element(SubRootElement);
            }
        }

        protected virtual XDocument Compile() {
            XElement root = new XElement(RootElement);
            root.Add(new XAttribute("xmlns", XMLNameSpace));
            if (XMLVersion != null) {
                root.Add(new XAttribute("version", XMLVersion));
            }
            if (SubRootElement != null) {
                root.Add(new XElement(SubRootElement));
            }
            return new XDocument(root);
        }

        public abstract ResponseType Send();

        protected abstract ResponseType CreateResponse(CW1Request<ResponseType> request, string response);
    }

    public abstract class CW1Response : CW1Message {
        protected CW1Response(CW1Request<CW1Response> request, string response) : base(request.ConnectionConfig) {

        }
    }
   ```
3. UniversalRequest and UniversalResponse:

   ```
    public abstract class UniversalRequest<ResponseType> : CW1Request<ResponseType> where ResponseType : UniversalResponse {
        private DataContext _Context;

        protected UniversalRequest(CW1Connection conn) : base(conn) {
            Context = new DataContext(conn.CompanyCode, conn.EnterpriseId, conn.ServerId);
        }

        public override ResponseType Send() {
            HttpXmlClient client = new HttpXmlClient(ConnectionConfig.HttpXmlURI, true, ConnectionConfig.UserName, ConnectionConfig.UserPwd);
            string responseXML;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            using (var xw = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8)))
                this.Compile().Save(xw);
            byte[] requestBytes = ms.ToArray();
            using (var sourceStream = new MemoryStream(requestBytes)) {
                try {
                    var response = client.Post(sourceStream);
                    var responseStatus = response.StatusCode;

                    if (responseStatus != HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                        Trace.TraceError(ConnectionConfig.CompanyCode + " - Erreur HTTP, Statut:- " + (int)responseStatus + " - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                        throw new CW1Exception("Erreur de communication HTTP.");
                    } else {
                        if (response.Content != null) {
                            Stream stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
                            if (response.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Contains("gzip", StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
                                stream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
                            }
                            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
                                responseXML = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Trace.TraceError("Le serveur a renvoyé une réponse vide pour la société " + ConnectionConfig.CompanyCode + ".");
                            throw new CW1Exception("Le serveur a renvoyé une réponse vide pour la société " + ConnectionConfig.CompanyCode + ".");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    if (ex is CW1Exception) throw ex;
                    Trace.TraceError(ex.ToString());
                    if (ex is ArgumentOutOfRangeException || ex is ObjectDisposedException || ex is InvalidOperationException) throw new CW1Exception("Erreur de lecture du flux de données.");
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
            return CreateResponse(this, responseXML);
        }

        protected override XDocument Compile() {
            XDocument doc = base.Compile();
            getRoot(doc).Add(Context.ToXML());
            return doc;
        }

        protected override string XMLNameSpace { get => "http://www.XXXXXXX.com/Schemas/Universal"; }
        internal DataContext Context { get => _Context; set => _Context = value; }
    }

    public abstract class UniversalResponse : CW1Response {
        //Error on request word in base constructor.
        internal UniversalResponse(UniversalRequest<UniversalResponse> request, string response) : base(request, response) {
            //TODO
        }
    }
   ```
4. TransactionBatchRequest and TransactionBatchResponse:

   ```
    public class TransactionBatchRequest : UniversalRequest<TransactionBatchResponse> {
        public TransactionBatchRequest(CW1Connection conn) : base(conn) {

        }

        protected override string RootElement { get => "UniversalTransactionBatchRequest"; }
        protected override string SubRootElement { get => "TransactionBatchRequest"; }

        //Can't use TransactionBatchRequest<TransactionBatchResponse> here.
        protected override TransactionBatchResponse CreateResponse(CW1Request<TransactionBatchResponse> request, string response) {
            Trace.TraceInformation(response);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class TransactionBatchResponse : UniversalResponse {
        //Error on request word in base constructor.
        internal TransactionBatchResponse(CW1Request<CW1Response> request, string response) : base(request, response) {
            //TODO
        }
    }
   ```

The issue is in that code snippet:

internal UniversalResponse(UniversalRequest request, string response) : base(**request**, response) {}

*Argument1:impossible conversion from 'UniversalRequest' to 'CW1Request'.*

Whereas UniversalRequest inherits from CW1Request, and UniversalResponse inherits from CW1Response. I imagine the compiler doesn't like adding a more restrictive constraint, but I don't know how to write this correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lays within how inheritance works when using generic types.

```
B_Response inherits from A_Response

B_Request<T> inherits from A_Request<T>
```

even if T1 inherits from T2

```
B_Request<T1> NEVER INHERITS FROM B_Request<T2>
```

this means that B_Request<B_Response> does not inherit from A_Request<A_Response> and you can't use the base constructor of A_Response if designed in this way.
This is the same of passing a List< String> to a method who has a List< object> as input. This method could add an object to the list of strings and this is not correct.

Based on the differences between A_Request, B_Request, A_Response and B_Response there could be many options.
If you can share your code we could find a solution together.

If you just want to compile, just leave the constructors empty.

Comment: Thanks.
I added a little more details except all the methods not useful to study this case. How then can I pass the parameter to the constructor of my base class?

Comment: if B_Response does not add any method or change any logic to A_Response just don't use B_Response and use always A_Response

Comment: The descendants of A_Response parse the response XML string parameter using different logics. The responses are built within the Send() method of the corresponding requests.


I think the best I could do is modifying the responses constructors to always use A_Request<A_Response> and make it internal (as the response is always built by the request). I call the response constructor with the request in order to transmit all the context informations at the same time, but I think I could use a override method or property and rely on polymorphism.

Comment: Oh... I can't do this, since my constructor won't want my parameter either ... I'm just moving the problem ...

Comment: Could you add the detail of the "Send" method to the snippet please?

Comment: I change the original post to include actual code.
There may be inconsistencies between the different levels of inheritance as I do different tests.